# WMI Process Watching uses too much CPU! Any better method?

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

I need to watch when certain processes are started or stopped on a Windows machine. I'm currently tapped into the WMI system and querying it every 5 seconds, but this causes a CPU spike every 5 seconds because WMI is WMI. Is there a better way of doing this? I could just make a list of running processes and attach an Exited event to them through the System.Diagnostics Namespace, but there is no Event Handler for creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly how you'd do it in the real world but should help. This seems not to drive my CPU much at all.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Getting all instances of notepad
        // (this is only done once here so start up some notepad instances first)
        // you may want use GetProcessByPid or GetProcesses and filter them as required
        Process[] processesToWatch = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

        foreach (var process in processesToWatch)
        {
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            process.Exited +=
                (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("An instance of notepad exited");
        }

        Thread watchThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
                    foreach (var process in processes)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", process.Id, process.ProcessName);
                    }
                    // Don't dedicate a thread to this like I'm doing here
                    // setup a timer or something similiar
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
            });
        watchThread.IsBackground = true;
        watchThread.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Polling processes and waiting for notepad process exit events");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: This is the route I ended up going after I couldn't get the WMI to be nicer to me.

Comment: I used a similar technique for monitoring all process launches and terminations. Even with a very small sleep (50ms) within the loop my CPU runs at ~0%. Once the PID is obtained this way I call Win32_Process and get extra process info not present (or difficult to obtain without an exception being thrown) via the Process class.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only looking for PID/Name of your processes, you may instead wish to pick up on Win32_ProcessTrace events, using a WQL query such as "SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessTrace WHERE TargetInstance.ProcessName = 'name'" **if applicable***.

The pitfall of using "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32Process' AND TargetInstance.Name = 'name'" is in how it works on the back end.  If you inspect wbemess.log within your %windir%\system32\wbem\logs directory, you will notice the following logs (using __InstanceDeletionEvent):

```
(Wed Jul 22 13:58:31 2009.73889577) : Registering notification sink with query select * from __InstanceDeletionEvent within 10 where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' in namespace //./root/CIMV2.
(Wed Jul 22 13:58:31 2009.73889577) : Activating filter 047209E0 with query select * from __InstanceDeletionEvent within 10 where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' in namespace //./root/CIMV2.
(Wed Jul 22 13:58:31 2009.73889577) : Activating filter 0225E560 with query select * from __ClassOperationEvent where TargetClass isa "Win32_Process" in namespace //./root/CIMV2.
(Wed Jul 22 13:58:31 2009.73889577) : Activating filter 'select * from __ClassOperationEvent where TargetClass isa "Win32_Process"' with provider $Core
(Wed Jul 22 13:58:31 2009.73889587) : Activating filter 'select * from __InstanceDeletionEvent within 10 where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'' with provider $Core
(Wed Jul 22 13:58:31 2009.73889587) : Instituting polling query select * from Win32_Process to satisfy event query select * from __InstanceDeletionEvent within 10 where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'
(Wed Jul 22 13:58:31 2009.73889587) : Executing polling query 'select * from Win32_Process' in namespace '//./root/CIMV2'
(Wed Jul 22 13:58:31 2009.73889697) : Polling query 'select * from Win32_Process' done
(Wed Jul 22 13:58:41 2009.73899702) : Executing polling query 'select * from Win32_Process' in namespace '//./root/CIMV2'
(Wed Jul 22 13:58:41 2009.73899792) : Polling query 'select * from Win32_Process' done
```

As you can see, the actual event implementation on the remote machine is to perform a query against Win32_Process on an interval that is specified by your value in the WITHIN clause.  As a result, any processes that start and stop within that poll will never fire an event.

You can set the WITHIN clause to a small value to try and minimize this effect, but the better solution is to use a true event like Win32_ProcessTrace, which should **always** fire.

*Note that MSDN indicates Win32_ProcessTrace requires a minimum of Windows XP on a client machine and Windows 2003 on a server machine to work.  If you are working with an older OS, you may be stuck using the __InstanceModificationEvent query.

Answer (score 2):

I've had CPU spikes when listening to WMI events in cases where I have failed to detach properly from my events on exit/cleanup. You might want to check you are not "leaking" WMI event subscriptions. Just in case detach from the event as early as possible and make sure you always do it.

To illustrate further, here's an example from [my PowerShell book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599403) that listens to WMI events using the PSEventing library:

> Add-PSSnapin PSEventing -ErrorAction
>   SilentlyContinue
>
> $queryString = @'
>       SELECT * 
>       FROM __InstanceModificationEvent
>       WITHIN 10
>       WHERE 
>           TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Service'
>           AND   TargetInstance.Name = 'w3svc'
>           AND   TargetInstance.State = 'Stopped' '@
>
> $query = New-Object System.Management.WQLEventQuery `
>       -argumentList $queryString
>
> $watcher = New-Object
>   System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher($query)
>
> Connect-EventListener watcher
>   EventArrived
>
> $watcher.Start()
>
> echo "Waiting for the W3CSVC service
>   to stop..." Get-Event -wait | 
>       `foreach {`
>           Write-Host -foreground Red "The W3SVC service has stopped!" 
>       }
>
> $watcher.Stop()
>
> Disconnect-EventListener watcher EventArrived
>
> echo "done"

If I do not do the **Disconnect-EventListener** bit upon script exit, I get CPU spikes the third or fourth time I attach to the event. My guess is that the system still tries to deliver events.

Answer (score 1):

My answer here mentions an alternative other than WMI:https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315772/3721646 
WMI queries can cost heavy CPU performance if not designed properly. If an intrinsic event from Win32_Process class is used to track process creation event, this impacts performance heavily. An alternate approach is to leverage Security Audit logs. You can enable Process Tracking using Local Security Policy or using a GPO in case of multiple machines. Once the process tracking starts, you can subscribe to security event logs with a custom XML query to monitor certain processes of your interest. The process creation event ID is 4688. `

```
<QueryList>
 <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
   <Select Path="Security">
       *[EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName'] ='C:\Windows\explorer.exe']]
       and
       *[System[(EventID=4688)]]
   </Select>
 </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: would be nice to see how it can be done in c#