# Windows API - Window registration event

Tags: winapi, events, window, registration

Is there any event function in WinAPI that allows catching window registration moment by it's class name? For exaple trigger event when application starts or create new window.
I've found EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE but it doesn't seem to catch proper event. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to catch calls to `RegisterClass`?  There isn't an event for that.  What problem are you trying to solve by capturing window registrations?

Comment: @shf301 I'm trying to catch specific application start (and end) instead of looping `while(1)`

Comment: You can [monitor processes starting and stopping using WMI as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556048/how-to-detect-win32-process-creation-termination-in-c).