# How to detect new processes

Tags: process

Is there a way to detect process starts (whena new program is run) without EnumProcesses or any other listing and comparing method. Is there an event based approach?

Comment: On what sort of system?

Comment: On windows have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556048/how-to-detect-win32-process-creation-termination-in-c, on linux it might be possable to use inotify on procfs