# WIN 32 API to detect launched and terminated application/process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32com

I am looking for a WIN 32 API to detect application launch and termination in my application.
I am looking to develop a dockBar/TaskBar for which I need to get handle of application that are launch and terminate.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did that work? How did that *not* work (often as important to know what did work)?

Comment: Try searching before you ask. I believe your answer is already supplied here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556048/how-to-detect-win32-process-creation-termination-in-c

Comment: You can do this through WMI

Answer (score 2):

For a DockBar/TaskBar have a look at the [RegisterShellHookWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
Specifically, the `HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED` and `HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED` notification.

Comment: The answer to the question that _should_ have been asked.