# embed dll file into exe and release physical file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fody, fody-costura

using Fody/Costura to embedding dll file to single file is ok and all works good .
but if i physically put dll file in executable folder and run application , application hook dll file and when i want to edit or delete dll file it throw an exception that this file is use , is it possible to solve this problem ?

**--Update**
using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;` we can handle resoloving library . but if dll file exist in bin filder this method not fired to set loading library

Comment: Why not use single-file deployment in .Net core 3+? looks like custora is in maintenance mode due to this.

Comment: Well, don't run the application that is using the DLL (or exit it), and then the DLL should not be in use, allowing you to edit/delete the DLL...

Comment: The alternative is trying to forcefully close any file handles of this DLL file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645584/how-to-close-a-system-handle-or-some-open-file-handle-in-another-process), but i can't tell if this will be easy with memory-mapped files such as DLLs. Doing this will inevitably make _any_ running apps using this DLL unstable, leading to those apps crashing when they attempt to call any code in the DLL they lost access to...

Comment: @JonasH I am using .net Framework

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace two app in some folder are usinng same library and i want to update other , at this time because library is in use . it cant modify . so i want to embedded one