# WinApi C++ \ Creating an app that needs an event to trigger every few seconds or so

Tags: c++, winapi

Creating an app that needs an event to trigger every few seconds or so.

I'm used to game design where a simple `EventTick()` that is handled by the engine does all the work. How can I make an event like this in the WinApi desktop wizard. I need to check a Proc Id in intermittent periods.

Thinking something like-

```
case WM_TICK:
{do thing}
break;
```

Or any other way to do this. I have also looked into `WM_Timers` but was getting mixed results so was thinking there was probably another way.

Comment: Go read [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Windows%C2%AE-Fifth-Developer-Reference/dp/157231995X) . Save money and order a used copy.

Comment: If you already have a GUI message loop then [WM_TIMER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer) is the way to go. Otherwise look at [waitable timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects).

Comment: *"I need to check a Proc Id in intermittent periods"* - Sounds like you want to get notifications, when a particular process is terminated. A timer (or any method based on polling/sampling) is a poor choice for that. You can set up a callback when a process terminates. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3556048/1889329).

Answer (score 0):

To check if a process is still running, use EnumProcesses or CreateToolHelp32Snapshot to find your process, then use OpenProcess() with PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION to get a handle to the process.  Then use [GetExitCodeProcess()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess) to check if the process has terminated, if it hasn't the output variable will be STILL_ACTIVE

You can do this inside your message loop using [WM_TIMER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer)