# Callback function in RegisterWaitForSingleObject called when monitoring other process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32-process

Goal: I want to monitor notepad.exe and restart it whenever it terminates.

My program **should**,

1. starts notepad process using `ShellExecuteEx`
2. registers the started process with `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`
3. callback function `ProcessWaitCallback` invoked whenever the notepad process terminates.

But
My program *does*,

1. starts notepad process using `ShellExecuteEx`
2. registers the started process with `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`
3. callback function `ProcessWaitCallback` invoked as soon as I run the program resulting in a duplicate notepad process spawning up.

The problem is that as soon as I run the program, the callback gets executed (which I expect to get executed when I close the notepad process) resulting in 2 instances of notepad running.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <atlbase.h>

#include "conio.h"

using namespace ::std;

HANDLE hWaitHandle;
LPCSTR notepadExePath = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe";
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shellExecInfo = { 0 };

bool IsValidHandle(HANDLE hHandle, string logString) 
{
    bool returnVal = hHandle != NULL && hHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    cout << "IsValidHandle(): " << logString << " " << returnVal << endl;
    return returnVal;
}

SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShellExecEx(
    HWND hwnd,
    LPCSTR lpOperation,
    LPCSTR lpFile,
    LPCSTR lpParameters,
    LPCSTR lpDirectory,
    INT nShowCmd,
    ULONG fmask)
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO shellExecInfoLocal = { 0 };
    shellExecInfoLocal.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    shellExecInfoLocal.fMask = fmask;
    shellExecInfoLocal.hwnd = hwnd;
    shellExecInfoLocal.lpVerb = lpOperation;
    shellExecInfoLocal.lpFile = lpFile;
    shellExecInfoLocal.lpParameters = lpParameters;
    shellExecInfoLocal.lpDirectory = lpDirectory;
    shellExecInfoLocal.nShow = nShowCmd;
    shellExecInfoLocal.hInstApp = NULL;

    cout << "ShellExecEx(): Invoking LPCWSTR version of ShellExecEx" << endl;
    ShellExecuteEx(&shellExecInfoLocal);
    return shellExecInfoLocal;
}

// Callback function to be called when the process terminates
void CALLBACK ProcessWaitCallback(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    cout << "ProcessWaitCallback(): Process terminated. Restarting..." << std::endl;
    if (IsValidHandle(shellExecInfo.hProcess, "ProcessWaitCallback(): shellExecInfo.hProcess"))
    {
        CloseHandle(shellExecInfo.hProcess);
    }

    shellExecInfo = ShellExecEx(nullptr, "open", notepadExePath, "", "", SW_SHOWNORMAL, SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS);

    auto code = reinterpret_cast<INT_PTR>(shellExecInfo.hInstApp);
    if (code <= 32)
    {
        cout << "ProcessWaitCallback(): Error re-starting Windows 365:" << GetLastError() << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ProcessWaitCallback(): Restarted notepad with pid:" << GetProcessId(shellExecInfo.hProcess) << endl;
    }
    if (!RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
        &hWaitHandle,
        shellExecInfo.hProcess,
        ProcessWaitCallback,
        NULL,
        INFINITE,
        WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE))
    {
        cout << "ProcessWaitCallback(): Error registering wait operation: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    shellExecInfo = ShellExecEx(nullptr, "open", notepadExePath, "", "", SW_SHOWNORMAL, SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS);
    
    auto code = reinterpret_cast<INT_PTR>(shellExecInfo.hInstApp);
    if (code <= 32)
    {
        cout << "main(): Error Starting Notepad:" << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    DWORD w365ProcessId = GetProcessId(shellExecInfo.hProcess);
    cout << "main(): Process started successfully pid:" << w365ProcessId << endl;

    if (!RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
        &hWaitHandle,
        shellExecInfo.hProcess,
        ProcessWaitCallback,
        NULL,
        INFINITE,
        WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE
))
    {
        cout << "main(): Error registering wait operation: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    cout << "main(): Press any key to exit 1..." << std::endl;
    _getch();
    cout << "main(): Press any key to exit 2..." << std::endl;
    _getch();

    if (IsValidHandle(hWaitHandle, "main(): hWaitHandle"))
    {
        if (UnregisterWait(hWaitHandle) == 0)
        {
            cout << "main(): Error while unregistering wait handle. error:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "main(): Wait handle successfully unregistered." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    if (IsValidHandle(shellExecInfo.hProcess, "main(): shellExecInfo.hProcess"))
    {
        if (CloseHandle(shellExecInfo.hProcess) == 0)
        {
            cout << "main(): Error while closing process handle. error:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "main(): Process handle successfully closed." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows (without me killing the notepad that opens up)

```
.\MonitorNotepad_WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE.exe
ShellExecEx(): Invoking LPCWSTR version of ShellExecEx
main(): Process started successfully pid:46116
main(): Press any key to exit 1...
ProcessWaitCallback(): Process terminated. Restarting...
IsValidHandle(): ProcessWaitCallback(): shellExecInfo.hProcess 1
ShellExecEx(): Invoking LPCWSTR version of ShellExecEx
ProcessWaitCallback(): Restarted notepad with pid:39648
```

See how even though I don't close the notepad process still the line `ProcessWaitCallback(): Process terminated. Restarting...` gets printed.

Update 1:
I see the exact same behavior with CreateProcess as well

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"

using namespace::std;

void CALLBACK ProcessExitCallback(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    std::cout << "Process has exited asynchronously." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    LPSTR processPath = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"; // Replace with your actual process path

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    if (CreateProcess(
        nullptr,
        processPath,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        FALSE,
        0,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &si,
        &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

        HANDLE waitHandle = NULL;

        if (RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&waitHandle, pi.hProcess, &ProcessExitCallback, nullptr, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE))
        {
            std::cout << "Asynchronous wait registered. Waiting for process exit..." << std::endl;
            _getch();
            _getch();
            if (CloseHandle(pi.hProcess) == 0) 
            { cout << "CloseHandle error" << endl; }
            else { cout << "CloseHandle success" << endl; }
            if (UnregisterWait(waitHandle) == 0) 
            { cout << "UnregisterWait error" << endl; } 
            else 
            { cout << "UnregisterWait success" << endl; }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to register asynchronous wait. Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create the process. Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

here is the output without me closing the notepad process

```
Asynchronous wait registered. Waiting for process exit...
Process has exited asynchronously.
CloseHandle success
UnregisterWait success
```

Comment: Return local variable already error, return struct.. why shellexecute instead CreateProcess..hInstApp- what is this ?! This is not process handle. You even not try use hProcess. All code is wrong

Comment: @RbMm I am using ShellExecuteEx cause the actual codebase I am working on uses `ShellExecuteEx` api. The program I pasted here (monitoring and restarting notepad) is just a POC that I am doing.

Comment: @RbMm what do you mean by "Return local variable already error, return struct"?

Comment: For my looking this is obvious. All code is wrong

Comment: oops I followed https://mytechcraze.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/the-registerwaitforsingleobject-to-monitor-a-process/. Any other sources I may refer?

Comment: @coda do you have the same problem with premature signaling if you use `WaitForSingleObject()` instead of `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()`? Are you sure you are actually waiting on the main Notepad process you see onscreen (ie verify the logged process ID with Task Manager) and not a temporary process that exits as soon as it runs (ie, after sending new info to the main process)?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `c:\windows\notepad.exe` simply launches `c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe` and exits. You need to launch the latter to get the desired behavior.

Comment: @Luke - *c:\windows\notepad.exe simply launches c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe and exits* - this is not true

Comment: @coda What operating system are you running? Both code samples behave as expected for me on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Notepad is not a great choice to test this code.  On Win11, c:\windows\notepad.exe actually starts another appx process and terminates.  You'll see it running, even though you got a notification that it completed.  Settings > Apps > Advanced app settings > App execution aliases > turn if off for Notepad.

Comment: @HansPassant yes this was the issue. When I turned the alias off it works perfectly. Any idea how to get around this in case I can't turn this alias thing off? So the actual app I am trying to monitor is also listed under ettings > Apps > Advanced app settings > App execution aliases

Comment: @coda try creating a [Job object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects) and launch Notepad inside of that job, and then wait for the Job to notify you when all processes in the job have terminated. Any child processes will automatically be added to the parent's Job by default.

Answer (score 1):

instead `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` better use `CreateThreadpoolWait` once and `SetThreadpoolWait` (every time when you start new process). this api internally called by `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. code can be next:

```
class RundownProtection
{
    LONG _Value;

public:

    enum {
        v_complete = 0, v_init = 0x80000000
    };

    BOOL IsRundownCompleted()
    {
        return v_complete == _Value;
    }

    _NODISCARD BOOL IsRundownBegin()
    {
        return 0 <= _Value;
    }

    _NODISCARD BOOL Acquire()
    {
        LONG Value, NewValue;

        if (0 > (Value = _Value))
        {
            do 
            {
                NewValue = InterlockedCompareExchangeNoFence(&_Value, Value + 1, Value);

                if (NewValue == Value) return TRUE;

            } while (0 > (Value = NewValue));
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    _NODISCARD BOOL Release()
    {
        return InterlockedDecrement(&_Value) == v_complete;
    }

    // if (Acquire()) { Rundown_l(); Release(); }
    void Rundown_l()
    {
        InterlockedBitTestAndReset(&_Value, 31);
    }

    RundownProtection(LONG Value = v_complete) : _Value(Value)
    {
    }

    BOOL Init()
    {
        return InterlockedCompareExchange(&_Value, v_init, v_complete) == v_complete;
    }
};

struct AR 
{
    PTP_WAIT _M_Wait = 0;
    RundownProtection _M_lock = RundownProtection::v_init;

    static VOID CALLBACK _S_WaitCallback(
        _In_ PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE /*Instance*/,
        _In_ PVOID Context,
        _In_ PTP_WAIT Wait,
        _In_ TP_WAIT_RESULT WaitResult
        )
    {
        reinterpret_cast<AR*>(Context)->WaitCallback(Wait, WaitResult);
    }

    VOID WaitCallback(
        _In_ PTP_WAIT Wait,
        _In_ TP_WAIT_RESULT WaitResult
        )
    {
        switch (WaitResult)
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            if (_M_lock.Acquire())
            {                   
                Start(Wait);

                if (_M_lock.Release())
                {
                    CloseThreadpoolWait(Wait);
                    delete this;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    void Start(_In_ PTP_WAIT Wait)
    {
        static const WCHAR notepad[] = L"\\notepad.exe";
        WCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
        if (ULONG cch = GetWindowsDirectoryW(buf, _countof(buf)))
        {
            if (cch <= _countof(buf) - _countof(notepad))
            {
                memcpy(buf + cch, notepad, sizeof(notepad));

                STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
                if (CreateProcessW(buf, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
                {
                    NtClose(pi.hThread);
                    SetThreadpoolWait(Wait, pi.hProcess, 0);
                    NtClose(pi.hProcess);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (PTP_WAIT Wait = CreateThreadpoolWait(_S_WaitCallback, this, 0))
        {
            _M_Wait = Wait;
            Start(Wait);
        }
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        if (_M_lock.Acquire())
        {
            _M_lock.Rundown_l();

            if (_M_lock.Release())
            {
                if (_M_Wait)
                {
                    WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks(_M_Wait, TRUE);
                    CloseThreadpoolWait(_M_Wait);
                }

                delete this;
            }
        }
    }
};

void demo()
{
    if (AR* p = new AR)
    {
        p->Start();

        MessageBoxW(0,0,0,0);

        p->Stop();
    }
}
```

if use `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` then

```
struct AR 
{
    HANDLE _M_hWaitObject = 0;
    SRWLOCK _M_lock {};
    LONG _M_dwRef = 1;
    BOOLEAN _M_bStop = FALSE;

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrementNoFence(&_M_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_M_dwRef))
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    static VOID CALLBACK _S_WaitOrTimerCallback(
        _In_  PVOID lpParameter,
        _In_  BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired
        )
    {
        if (TimerOrWaitFired)
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }
        reinterpret_cast<AR*>(lpParameter)->WaitOrTimerCallback();
    }

    VOID WaitOrTimerCallback()
    {
        AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&_M_lock);

        if (HANDLE hWaitObject = _M_hWaitObject)
        {
            _M_hWaitObject = 0;

            if (UnregisterWaitEx(hWaitObject, 0) || ERROR_IO_PENDING != GetLastError())
            {
                __debugbreak();
            };
        }

        if (!_M_bStop)
        {
            Start();
        }

        ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&_M_lock);

        Release();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        static const WCHAR notepad[] = L"\\notepad.exe";
        WCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
        if (ULONG cch = GetWindowsDirectoryW(buf, _countof(buf)))
        {
            if (cch <= _countof(buf) - _countof(notepad))
            {
                memcpy(buf + cch, notepad, sizeof(notepad));

                STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
                if (CreateProcessW(buf, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
                {
                    NtClose(pi.hThread);

                    AddRef();
                    if (!RegisterWaitForSingleObject(&_M_hWaitObject, pi.hProcess, 
                        _S_WaitOrTimerCallback, this, INFINITE, WT_EXECUTEONLYONCE))
                    {
                        Release();
                    }
                    NtClose(pi.hProcess);
                    __nop();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        _M_bStop = TRUE;

        AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&_M_lock);

        if (HANDLE hWaitObject = _M_hWaitObject)
        {
            _M_hWaitObject = 0;

            if (UnregisterWaitEx(hWaitObject, 0))
            {
                Release();
            }
            else if (ERROR_IO_PENDING != GetLastError())
            {
                __debugbreak();
            }
        }

        ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&_M_lock);
    }
};

void demo()
{
    if (AR* p = new AR)
    {
        p->Start();

        MessageBoxW(0,0,0,0);

        p->Stop();

        p->Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have described is just an optimization, but it won't solve the OP's actual issue.  The problem is not in HOW the code is waiting, but WHAT it is waiting on.