# Capturing user ran programs

Tags: c#, process

I am looking for a way to record when certain programs have been executed.

For instance, if Microsoft Word has been started I would like to write out a time and date stamp along with the program name.

The output I get. I may change it to an Excel spreadsheet. Just need a little guidance on where to look to capture user run programs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-sharp-process-monitor

Comment: whoever posted the link above me, I'm so sorry, I accidentally overwrote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the ManagementEventWatcher

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455873/how-to-detect-a-process-start-end-using-c-sharp-in-windows)

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.aspx)

As for creating an excel spreadsheet from data, you can easily find code for that.

[like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20228/Using-C-to-Create-an-Excel-Document)

Comment: Jonesy,
Perfect.  exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks also for the extras.  Much appreciated.  All of my searches on here didn't turn up ManagementEventWatcher.

-J

Comment: Awesome.  I didn't even know about it till I did some research for your question. Handy to know.

Comment: Also, if my answer did help you, I'd very much appreciate it if you marked it as the selected answer