# How can I detect starting of process?

Tags: c#, process

How can I detect starting of a new process? I wanna kill some other than my processes, when they are starting. Is there any way to that?

Comment: **Please give a comment why are you downvoting my question. Thank you**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect a process start & end using c# in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455873/how-to-detect-a-process-start-end-using-c-sharp-in-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Well*, your question is not clear but you should have a look [`Process.GetProcessesByName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) method.

> Creates an array of new Process components and associates them with
>   all the process resources on the local computer that share the
>   specified process name.

For example;

```
Process[] Runningcmd = Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd");
if (Runningcmd.Length == 0)
  Console.WriteLine("Command Line is not running");
else
    foreach(var p in Runningcmd )
    {
       p.Kill();
    }
```